# AdMob ad is showing in iOS simulator, but not on iDevice

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, admob

As the heading states, I can get my AdMob Ad to show in the iOS 5.1 and 6.0 simulator just fine, however, when running my application on my iOS 5.1.1 or 6.0 devices, there is just a blank space where the ad should be served. The code in my .m file is as follows:

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                                            411.0 -
                                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"**myID**";
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

//GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
//r.testing = YES;
//[bannerView_ loadRequest:r];
```

Furthermore, if I initiate testing of ads (see commented-out section), the test ad shows on both the simulator AND my iDevices, which is baffling me! What am I missing?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up from my question, I have found that since I am jailbroken and have installed Lockinfo (I believe this is the culprit), I also have an Ad blocker installed. If any others come across this issue, ensure to test on a non-jailbroken device, and the Ad should display as expected.

Comment: I'm getting this problem too!  I don't have LockInfo installed though, just an ad blocker like you did.  I think this is actually an AdMob bug.  Clearly they should still be able to serve ads to *my* app while the ad blocker blocks ads in all other apps.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm sure it was something to do with being jailbroken regardless, since it worked okay on other devices. Although as you said, definitely could be an Admob thing. Very weird indeed.

Comment: ROFL! I know this is 2 years old now but I just ran into it! Developers adding Ads to their apps, but have ad blockers installed! Good job!